# Ultrasonic sensor interfacing with PIC18F4520 Controller

Tags: c

I am trying to display distance on my lcd but its is displaying junk data on it

Steps of Programming

PIC18F4520 microcontroller needs to transmit at least 10 us trigger pulse to the HC-SR04 Trig Pin.
After getting trigger pulse, HC-SR04 automatically sends eight 40 kHz sound wave and waits for  rising edge 
output at Echo pin.
When the rising edge capture occurs at Echo pin which is connected to the input of PIC18F4520, start Timer of PIC18F4520 and again wait for falling edge on Echo pin.
As soon as the falling edge is captured at the Echo pin, microcontroller read the count of the Timer. This time count is used to calculate the distance to an object.
Calculation (distance in cm)

Sound velocity =        343 m/s = 34300 cm/s = 34.3cm/msec = 0.0343cm/usec

Distance=speed*time

= (34300 * TIMER) / 2   = 17150 * (TIMER)  =17150xT(sec)   =0.01715xT (usec)   =17.15 xT (msec)

i have tried in different ways but unable to display correct distance  here is my code

```
#include<p18f4520.h>                
#include<string.h>                   

void delay_ms(int ms);
void delay_us(int us);
void Data(char Value);             
void Cmd(char Value);                
void Send2Lcd(const char Adr,rom const char *Lcd);

void main()                            
{
    char Dist_Array1[5];
    int Time=0,j=0;
    int Distance;   
    TRISB=0XFF;
    TRISC=0X00;        /*  (RC1,RC0 - >O/P Setting by Zero)      */
    TRISD=0X00;        /*  PORTD (0 - 7)pins Config as Output    */
    delay_ms(15);                      /*  Minimum 
                Delay To Power On LCD Module To Recieve Mode*/
    Cmd(0X30);  delay_ms(5);          /*  LCD                      Specification Commands                          */
    Cmd(0X30);  delay_ms(1);          /*  LCD                         Specification Commands                          */
    Cmd(0X30);  delay_ms(2);          /*  LCD                       Specification Commands                          */
    Cmd(0X38);                         /*  LCD Double                       Line Display Command                     */
    Cmd(0X06);                         /*  LCD Auto                    Increment Location Address Command         */
    Cmd(0X01);                         /*  LCD Display                        Clear Command                           */
    Cmd(0X0C);                         /*  LCD Display                     ON Command                              */
    Send2Lcd(0x80,"  Distance");
    Send2Lcd(0xc0,"Measurement");
    delay_ms(3);
    delay_ms(1000);

    TMR1H=0; TMR1L=0;       /* Load Timer1 with 0*/
    OSCCON=0x72;        /* Use internal                    oscillator frequency */

    while(1)
    {  
        Cmd(0x01);
        PORTCbits.RC3=0;    // trigger OFF
        delay_us(2);
        PORTCbits.RC3=1; // trigger ON
        delay_us(10);       
        PORTBbits.RB1=0; // trigger OFF

        while(PORTBbits.RB0==0 );       // RB0 is             connected to Echo pin
        T1CONbits.TMR1ON=1;         
        TMR1H=0; 
        TMR1L=0;        /* Load Timer1 with 0*/

        while(PORTBbits.RB0==1  );          
        T1CONbits.TMR1ON=0;

        Time = (TMR1L | (TMR1H<<8)); 
        Distance = (int)(Time/58.2);
        Cmd(0x01); 
        for(j=0;j<=2;j++)
        {
            Dist_Array1[j]=Distance%10+'0';  
            Distance=Distance/10;
        }
        Cmd(0x80);
        for(j=2;j>=0;j--)
        {
            Data(Dist_Array1[j]);
            delay_ms(100);           
        }
    }
    Cmd(0x01); 
}   

void Cmd(char Value){
     PORTD=Value;
     PORTCbits.RC1=0;    /*  RC1=0(RS=0)                        [Command Registr Selection])    */
     PORTCbits.RC0=0;   /*  RC0=0(R/W=0)    [Write                  Process])                */
    PORTCbits.RC2=1;                /*     RC2=1(Enable=1)  [Enable Line ON]                */
    delay_ms(4);                    /*  Minimun Delay                For Hold On Data                      */
    PORTCbits.RC2=0;                /*  
    RC2=0(Enable=0) [Enable Line OFF]               */
}   

void Data(char Value){
    PORTD=Value;
    PORTCbits.RC1=1;               /*  RC1=1(RS=1)                                [Data Registr Selection])       */
    PORTCbits.RC0=0;                /*  RC0=0(R/W=0)                      [Write Process])                */
    PORTCbits.RC2=1;               /*  RC2=1(Enable=1)                       [Enable Line ON]                */
    delay_ms(4);                   /*  Minimun Delay                    For Hold On Data                      */
    PORTCbits.RC2=0;               /*  RC2=0(Enable=0)                      [Enable Line OFF]               */
}

void Send2Lcd(const char Adr,rom const char *Lcd)
{
     Cmd(Adr);
     while(*Lcd!='\0')  
     {
        Data(*Lcd); 
        Lcd++;  
      }
}

void delay_ms(int ms)
{
    int i,count;
    for(i=1;i<=ms;i++)
    {
        count=498;
        while(count!=1)
        {
            count--;
        }
    }
}

void delay_us(int us)
{
    us=us>>1;
    while(us!=1)
        us--;
}
```

Comment: What junk data compared to what should be displayed?

Comment: Isn’t it an error to turn on trigger pin on RC1 pin by setting it with 1 and turning it off by RB1 with 0. That didn’t look so convenient to me. If it’s right thing to do can you give details of the ports?

Comment:  Please try not to use ALL CAPS as it's considered YELLING.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is NOT a diagnosable problem. Be specific: what output do you get and what do you expect? Can you confirm that the echo time you are trying to display is a sensible (displayable) value?

Answer (score 2):

> When the rising edge capture occurs at Echo pin which is connected to the input of PIC18F4520, start Timer of PIC18F4520 and again wait for falling edge on Echo pin. As soon as the falling edge is captured at the Echo pin, microcontroller read the count of the Timer.

This doesn't measure the echo delay. It measures the echo *duration*, which has nothing to do with the distance. You should start the timer as soon as the signal is generated, and read the timer as soon as the rising edge is captured.

There is more work to rule out noise, deal the no echo whatsoever, debouncing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure it's a bad idea to clear a timer after you've started it running:

```
while(PORTBbits.RB0==0 );       // RB0 is             connected to Echo pin
T1CONbits.TMR1ON=1;         
TMR1H=0; 
TMR1L=0;        /* Load Timer1 with 0*/
```

At the very least your final time will be short by the time it takes for the two instructions to execute.  In the worst case, the whole reading could be garbage.